# How to change content of ::after on hover

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to achieve a simple effect. What i want to do is set content for ::after an element and when the content is hovered i want to set the content to an empty string.

`div::after{ content: 'Something'; }`

`div:hover::after{ content: ''; }`
I tried doing this but the content just keep flickering

Comment: The content will flicker because as soon as you set it to empty the div is no longer hovered, or changes size anyway [depending on what else there is in  the div and where the hover is occurring], so goes back to the text, then that is immediately hovered and so it goes on.